# What would cause a responsive site to default to mobile?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a site with a responsive grid system using media-queries with break points. On IE8 I've seen the "mobile version" as the default view even with the screen size set to what should be the standard desktop size (greater than 960px wide).

Is there a known issue (and fix) that would cause this to happen?

thanks for the help, as always.

---- edit ----

how my media query is setup:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IE8 doesn't support media queries](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries), so probably it's processing all the CSS rules, even those a full-width screen shouldn't.

To prevent this problem, add the `only` keyword after each `@media` rule ( `@media only screen ...` ).

Then you can reach support including the fantastic plugin **[respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)** in the `<head>` section of all your pages

Comment: What's is interesting is my client sees this issue and I can't recreate it. They've sent me screen shots so I know what they are seeing is the mobile version. Hard to fix something I can test.

Comment: @dcp3450 i'm pretty sure [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) will do the job

Comment: I'm trying to avoid adding more load time to the site. I don't really need IE8 to be responsive. I just need IE8 to not load the responsive css.

Comment: added "only screen" and installed respond.js . They say the are still seeing the issue...

Comment: Nevermind, that actually fixed it. Apparently they weren't clearing their cache like I told them too.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you've built your code (and since you post none it is hard to tell what is wrong ;) ). But a possible issue is that you have defined your mobile layout first and the media query >960 doens't fire in IE8. Like this:

```
 body { // Default width for all browsers
   width: 300px; 
 }

 @media only screen and (min-width : 960px) { // Only for supporting desktops
   body {
     width: 960px;
   }
 }
```

(Always use a 'default' css (without media query) for browsers that don't support them.)

One way to deal with is could be to use the 960px wide layout as default:

```
 body { // Default width for all browsers
   width: 960px; 
 }

 @media only screen and (min-width : 1400px) { // Widescreen monitors
   body {
     width: 1400px;
   }
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width : 300px) { // Mobile layout
   body {
     width: 300px;
   }
 }
```

You will have to specify more then just the body of course, but this should give you an idea. If this does not solve the problem, then post some of your css here so we can have a look at it.